# Draw Here MapsView into a GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, here-api

I got a problem with drawing a mapView from the here-api into a glSurfaceView (it should be a glSurfaceView as some external devices requeres it to ensure good performance).

The map draws into a normal SurfaceView just perfectly.

I do the following steps to create the map-view in the GLSurfaceView:

---

1. Extend my view from GLSurfaceView:

> `public class MapView extends GLSurfaceView`

2. Setting the Renderer uppon initialisation in the ctors:

> ```
> setRenderer(...)
> ```

3. Start rendering after the map has been initialized:

> ```
> Renderer renderer = new MapOffScreenRenderer(getContext());
> renderer.setMap(map); //mapView, not null
> updateRendererSize(); //update the render size to the screen size
>
> renderer.start(getHolder(), surfaceUpdatedListener); // HERE COMES THE CRASH
> ```

It seems like the MapOffscreenRenderer crashes if i try to tell him to draw the map into the glSurfaceView.
The crash is a generic error: "12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering".

If i try to call the renderer.start() func (without the holder param), then everything is fine (the only bad thing is that the map is not being drawn).

The GlSurceView initialisation itself is fine as i am able to draw my own geometries into it.

Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

MapOffScreenRenderer internally uses a PBuffer backed surface and its own rendering thread and EGL context. It is not intended to be used to push into another GLSurfaceView surface. If you really want to do this then maybe create an independent OpenGL surface and share it between the GLSurfaceView and the MapOffScreenRenderer.

What use case are you try to accomplish using this type of design?

Comment: ok i do understand now why it chashes, thanks. You suggestion is to "share" the rendering between the GLSurfaceView and the MapOffscreenRenderer. What performance impact should i expect as the map going to be rendered twice, or do i miss something?                   The reason why i need the GLSurfaceView is: I have an external display which has a propriate mirror SDK to render content on the smartphone and send it to the display. This requires to use GLSurfaceView to render geometry based content to it.

Comment: If you render to a shared texture of some kind I do not anticipate too much performance problems. We have implemented similar use cases with the SDK. If performance is poor, consider turning off the extruded buildings. That should massively improve performance.